# Stop routing to login on expiring jwt token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwt

I have a question about a react project. If my jwt token runs out when im on a certain page that is accessible  without the token i still get rerouted to the login page is there anyway to stop this?

```
    //Set auth token header Auth
    setAuthToken(localStorage.jwtToken);
    //Decode
    const decoded = jwt_decode(localStorage.jwtToken);
    //Set user and isAuthenticated
    store.dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));

    //Check for expired token
    const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000;
    if (decoded.exp < currentTime) {
        //Logout user
        store.dispatch(logoutUser());
        // Redirect to login
        window.location.href = '/login';
    }
}
```

Comment: Not without seeing some code. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: This question is too vague. What your React app does when the jwt token expires is something that you have to program.

Comment: it depends on what logic you've written to keep the user inside the app until he is logged in, at least show some code.

Comment: See edited above. This is in my App.js can i check if the user is on a certain page here? and if he is not route him to login?

Comment: Sorry for not including the code at the start im working on a project my colleague left behind and i'm kinda new to a big react project